# Formatting Multi dimensional arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, format

How can I write a code that changes the values of each individual arrays within the multidimensional array `a` to zeroes right after there was a negative value. So the second array within `a` has a negative value `[12,34,5,6,88,-10,30,75]` of -10 that would turn all the values  of that and the values right after it to zeroes. Turning the array into `[12,34,5,6,88,0,0,0]`. How would I be able to get my Expected Output?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[12,45,50,60,30],
             [12,34,5,6,88,-10,30,75],
             [3,45,332,45,-12,-4,-64,12],
             [12,45,3,22,323]])
```

Expected Output:

```
[[12,45,50,60,30],
 [12,34,5,6,88,0,0,0],
 [3,45,332,45,0,0,0,0],
 [12,45,3,22,323]]
```

Comment: you should always show your own effort towards solving your question. Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a "write code for me" website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[12,45,50,60,30],
             [12,34,5,6,88,-10,30,75],
             [3,45,332,45,-12,-4,-64,12],
             [12,45,3,22,323]], dtype='object')


for l in a:
    for i in l:
        if i<0:
            l[l.index(i):] = [0] * len(l[l.index(i):])
            
a
```

output:

```
array([list([12, 45, 50, 60, 30]), list([12, 34, 5, 6, 88, 0, 0, 0]),
       list([3, 45, 332, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0]), list([12, 45, 3, 22, 323])],
      dtype=object)
```

second solution:

```
import numpy as np 

def neg_to_zero(l):
    for i in l:
        if i<0:
            l[l.index(i):] = [0] * len(l[l.index(i):])

a = np.array([[12,45,50,60,30],
             [12,34,5,6,88,-10,30,75],
             [3,45,332,45,-12,-4,-64,12],
             [12,45,3,22,323]], dtype='object')

list(map(neg_to_zero, a))

a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array:

```
In [608]: a = np.array([[12,45,50,60,30],
     ...:              [12,34,5,6,88,-10,30,75],
     ...:              [3,45,332,45,-12,-4,-64,12],
     ...:              [12,45,3,22,323]])
<ipython-input-608-894f7005e102>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  a = np.array([[12,45,50,60,30],
In [609]: a
Out[609]: 
array([list([12, 45, 50, 60, 30]), list([12, 34, 5, 6, 88, -10, 30, 75]),
       list([3, 45, 332, 45, -12, -4, -64, 12]),
       list([12, 45, 3, 22, 323])], dtype=object)
```

This contains lists the vary in length. It is not multidimensional. Making it an array, as opposed to leaving it as a list of lists, does not make it any easier to process.

Either way you have to iterate, and change each list separately.

Answer (score 0):

First, pay attention to the [answer by hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965422/2602877). Don't use numpy if your data is unsuitable. Your data is unsuitable for numpy because you have a list of lists where each contained list has a *different* length. It would be suitable for numpy if all had the *same* length (matrix shape).

To the problem itself: reduce it to solving the task on a single list, then transform each list.

```py
data = [
    [12, 45, 50, 60, 30],
    [12, 34, 5, 6, 88, -10, 30, 75],
    [3, 45, 332, 45, -12, -4, -64, 12],
    [12, 45, 3, 22, 323]
]
for row in data:
    transform(row)
```

The algorithm: we'll iterate over the list, and when we find the negative element, we know the current position, and then we can set all following elements.

I'll show you two variants.

The first variant uses slicing. It also uses `enumerate()`, which gives you `(index, value)` tuples for a list (or other iterable).

```py
def transform(lst):
    for (index, value) in enumerate(lst):
        if value < 0:
            lst[index:] = [0] * (len(lst) - index)
```

It creates a new list filled with zeroes by multiplying `[0]` (a 1-element list) by the length of the remainder. Then it assigns that to a slice of the list that is being transformed. This slice assignment changes the list itself.

The second variant works with a bit of "state":

```py
def transform(lst):
    do_overwrite = False
    for (index, value) in enumerate(lst):
        if value < 0:
            do_overwrite = True # "flips a switch", stay on
        if do_overwrite:
            lst[index] = 0
```

Python lists are objects, like pretty much everything else in python. That means, when you call a function and pass a list as an argument, the list isn't copied, but the function call gets that list object to work with. Any changes to that object... are "visible" to the caller, because it is the same list object that is handled.