# Formatting Multi dimensional array with values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

How can I write a code that changes the values of each individual arrays within the multidimensional array `a` to zeroes right after there was a negative or zero value for the `a` index or a value that is -100 or less for the `b` index. So the second array within `a` has no negative values but `b` has a -100 at the fourth index so everything after the fourth index is gonna be zeroes. `[45,50,60,30,23.2,232,-44,12,23]` `30` and the values right after it would turn into zeroes resulting in the output: `[45,50,60,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. The Expected Output with the `dtype ="object"` would have worked if not all the rows would have had the same length. How would I be able to get my Expected Output?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[12,45,50,-600,30,23.2,232,-44,12],
             [45,50,60,30,23.2,232,-44,12,23],
             [50,60,30,23.2,232,-44,12,34,12],
             [60,30,23.2,232,-44,12,120,3,4],
             [-300,23.2,232,-44,12,23,23,2,12],
             [23.2,-232,-44,12,34,1,2,300.3,5]], dtype='object')

b= np.array([-12.4,-13.4,-44,-100,-6.3,-11,-10,-1.1,-0.3])

#Going through rows
for row,l in enumerate(a):
    #inside row iteration
    for counter,i in enumerate(l):
        if i<0 or b[counter]<=-100:
            l[l.index(i):] = [0] * len(l[l.index(i):])
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Expected Output:

```
[[12,45,50,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[45,50,60,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[50,60,30,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[60,30,23.2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[23.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting Multi dimensional arrays Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964513/formatting-multi-dimensional-arrays-python)

Comment: Your array is fundamentally different from yesterday's.  Which is the real-life case?  2d arrays, or arrays of lists?  Making an array from list is just making life complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
for row,l in enumerate(a):
    #inside row iteration
    l = l.tolist()
    for counter,i in enumerate(l):
        if i<0 or b[counter]<=-100:
            a[row, l.index(i):] = [0] * len(l[l.index(i):])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[12 45 50 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [45 50 60 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [50 60 30 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [60 30 23.2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [23.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The reason it didn't work for you is because you need to convert it into a list before indexing it, also you got to assign it back into the array `a`

Comment: this is my answer and you copy this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964513/formatting-multi-dimensional-arrays-python/68964565#68964565

Comment: @user1740577 I didn't copy... I didn't even see that post...

Comment: @georgehere Does this work?

Comment: No worries I was not using that as an argument. I just wanted to say that that was my question as well. Yea it works

Comment: @georgehere, please clarify the above comments so that other may assist you as well.

Comment: @U12-Forward this is not an efficient answer. when working with NumPy you can solve this with just a `np.where` and `np.cumsum`. Its best to avoid using `for` loops when working with numpy. The whole point of numpy is to vectorize code.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal, in the original question, the sublists differed in length, so the array was 1d object dtype containing lists.  Here the sublists are the same, and the result is a 2d array.  So your approach works here, but not there.  Converting the rows to `tolist` allows him to use the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Agreed, but since there is no mention of the original post in the question and the cases mentioned here are 2d, I am forced to assume the same. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

When working with Numpy, you should avoid using any explicit for loops unless you just have to. Vectorization is the core advantage of using NumPy to begin with. You can solve this without using the slow `for` loops as  -

```
#Case 1
>>> n = -100
>>> np.where(np.cumsum(a<=c, axis=1) + np.cumsum(b<=c), 0, a)

array([[12, 45, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [45, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [50, 60, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [60, 30, 23.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [23.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Based on the conditions you have, you first need to create a boolean matrix (or 0s and 1s) based on which values you want to mask with 0. In this case, you can exploit a `np.cumsum` to propogate the `TRUE` values over `axis=1` after the first occurrence of your condition (<=-100). But since you are checking this with `b` as well, they can be added (which is equivalent to an `OR` operation) with broadcasting.

Therefore the logic looks like:

```
if: cumulative(condition1) OR cumulative(condition2), 
    return 0 
else: 
    return values from original array
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with one small change.  Don't try to make an object dtype array.  Leave it as a list of lists.

```
In [111]: alist = [[12,45,50,-600,30,23.2,232,-44,12],
     ...:              [45,50,60,30,23.2,232,-44,12,23],
     ...:              [50,60,30,23.2,232,-44,12,34,12],
     ...:              [60,30,23.2,232,-44,12,120,3,4],
     ...:              [-300,23.2,232,-44,12,23,23,2,12],
     ...:              [23.2,-232,-44,12,34,1,2,300.3,5]]
     ...: 
     ...: b= np.array([-12.4,-13.4,-44,-100,-6.3,-11,-10,-1.1,-0.3])
     ...: 
     ...: #Going through rows
     ...: for row,l in enumerate(alist):
     ...:     #inside row iteration
     ...:     for counter,i in enumerate(l):
     ...:         if i<0 or b[counter]<=-100:
     ...:             l[l.index(i):] = [0] * len(l[l.index(i):])
     ...: 
In [112]: alist
Out[112]: 
[[12, 45, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [45, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [50, 60, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [60, 30, 23.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [23.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Likewise with yesterday's sample:

```
In [114]: alist = [[12,45,50,60,30],
     ...:      ...:              [12,34,5,6,88,-10,30,75],
     ...:      ...:              [3,45,332,45,-12,-4,-64,12],
     ...:      ...:              [12,45,3,22,323]]
In [115]: for row,l in enumerate(alist):
     ...:      ...:     #inside row iteration
     ...:      ...:     for counter,i in enumerate(l):
     ...:      ...:         if i<0 or b[counter]<=-100:
     ...:      ...:             l[l.index(i):] = [0] * len(l[l.index(i):])
     ...: 
In [116]: alist
Out[116]: 
[[12, 45, 50, 0, 0],
 [12, 34, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [12, 45, 3, 0, 0]]
```